# Fill several parts of NumPy array, given a list of indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I want to fill a numpy.ndarray with data (32x32 pixel integer pictures==arrays)

From the name of the file of the picture I know where in my ndarray I want my values to be stored.

I would like to give my ndarray a list but also some slice(0) in it, because the picture is stored in the last two dimensions. How do I do that?

I would like to do something like

Pesudocode:

```
data=numpy.ndarray(dim1,dim2,dim3,32,32)
list=function(filename)

data[list,slice(0),slice(0)]=read_image(filename)
```

Is that possible?

My list has entries specifying the positions of the ndarray [int,int,int] and my read image is a 32 times 32 integer array (filling the last two dimension of my ndarray).

Comment: my list has entries specifying the positions of the ndarray [int,int,int] and my read image is a 32 times 32 integer array (filling the last two dimension of my ndarray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform this assignment, pass a suitable array in each of the first three dimensions, and `:` (meaning entire index range) in the last two  dimensions. 
If your list is, for example,

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 0], [5, 3, 4], [2, 2, 2]]
```

then the array to pass as the first index is [1, 4, 5, 2],  and similarly for two others: [2, 2, 3, 2] and [3, 0, 4, 2]. Complete example with fake (random) image:

```
data = np.zeros((6, 7, 8, 32, 32))
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 0], [5, 3, 4], [2, 2, 2]]
image = np.random.uniform(size=(32, 32))
ix = np.array(list)
data[ix[:, 0], ix[:, 1], ix[:, 2], :, :] = image
```

Here `ix[:, 0]` is [1, 4, 5, 2],  `ix[:, 1]` is `[2, 2, 3, 2]`, and so on.

Reference: [NumPy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Thanks! In my case I  had to modify it so I have a list and not a list of lists but except for that it worked fine!